# How do I run xunit tests for a Class Library (Package) project targeting net45?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xunit, dnx

I have a Class Library (Package) project, the new preview template in VS 2015 RTM from which I want to execute Xunit tests.

The solution builds fine but the Test Explorer doesn't find any tests. From the project.json you can see that I am only targeting net45, not dnx, so I am using xunit.runner.visualstudio.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "myproject": "",
        "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
        "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0-*"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "net45": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I change the project type to a normal Class Library, the tests are picked up. However since the code I am trying to test is a Class Library (package) project, referencing it from a normal Class Library is problematic and I was hoping that this would work. Is this (or some variation) possible?

**Context**

Normally this project type is used for ASP.NET 5, Core CLR, etc. Even though I'm only targeting net45, I am using it because I want to take advantage of the feature where I can seamlessly use local source code in place of a nuget package (via the global.json projects attribute). It makes it much easier to work on a package that depends upon another where I'm often making changes in both locally.

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems it can't be done right now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619892/how-to-run-xunit-tests-in-the-project-json-and-dotnet-tfm-world

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on DNX beta 7.0 than the xUnit declaration in project.json would need to look like this:

```
"dependencies": {

    "xunit": "2.1.0-rc1-build3168",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta5-build169"
  },
"commands": {

    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
```

and than i hope when you build the project the test will show up.
I have the similar problem until i did't use the correct version of xUnit with correct DNX version.

Here is the link where you can read more about the config. of xUnit and ASP.NET 5
http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html

I hope I helped.

Comment: Question : in case I've defined multiple framework in the project.json, how to start xunit from the commandline for a specific framework?

dnx --framework dnxcore50 -p test/Hello.Test does not seem to work ?