# How to run XUnit tests in the project.json and dotnet tfm world

Tags: xunit, dnx, project.json

Background: Recently I switched from the "old" world to the new project.json world, because new is always better ;)
Currently 2 out of 3 projects can use the "dotnet" target framework moniker, the other one needs the full .NET framework (net46).

I also switched my test projects to the new project.json world, but it I can´t run any tests. The build is green, but no tests are found.

I read [this](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html#create-class-library) documentation and included the xunit.runner.dnx, but the problem is that is is not a "dnx" project - it has a dependency on "dotnet" or "net46" and the current runner doesn´t seem to find the tests.

The project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Code-Inside/Sloader/blob/project.json/tests/Sloader.Config.Tests/project.json).

The error from the xunit.runner.dnx package:

> Error      The dependency xunit.runner.dnx 2.1.0-beta5-build169 in project Sloader.Config.Tests does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0.  Sloader.Config.Tests    C:\Users\Robert\Documents\GitHub\Sloader\tests\Sloader.Config.Tests\project.json    20  IntelliSense

Is this currently not supported or do I miss something? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can't be done right now. The issue is that the build system for `project.json` doesn't copy referenced DLLs from NuGet packages, unlike the old `packages.config` system. Until Microsoft fixes this behavior, you will not be able to do this. Your only recourse is to go back to `packages.config`.

Comment: Is this behavior by design or is this acknowledged as a bug within Microsoft?

Comment: Yes, we exchanged e-mail with a couple of the team members over this issue, and they acknowledged that it's a bug that they intend to fix.

Comment: There's some misinformation here but we should clarify guidance for this. It's coming. xproj and csproj will be able to reference each other. On top of that, unit testing still requires you to have a runner for each technology you want to test on.

Comment: The original poster didn't mention csproj => xproj references. He was asking how to run a non-DNX project.json unit test project with xUnit.net. And my information -- absolutely correct -- is that this is broken right now because of the failure to copy NuGet references to the bin folder.